# Is it possible in express JS to only accept one of two values in a path variable?

Tags: javascript, regex, express, rest, url

Let's say I have this GET url in my REST service:

```
router.get('/api/platform/:type', async (req, res) => {
    // something
}
```

I only want the request if `:type` is "windows" or "android". are there any way to do this in the url definition?

I think I've seen something like this before:

```
router.get('/api/platform/:type{windows|android}', async (req, res) => {
    // something
}
```

Something like that but it doesn't quite work for me.

Comment: Surely you mean a path variable, not a param?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl In Express, these are referred to as `params` right? `req.params` contains them. Also, the solution here is to check if your params matches and otherwise calling `next()`, so `if( ![ 'windows', 'macos' ].includes( req.param.type ) ) return next();`. I'm not sure putting this in the definition is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a regular expression in parentheses to a route parameter to validate its format:

```
router.get('/api/platform/:type(windows|android)', async (req, res) => {
    // something
}
```

> To have more control over the exact string that can be matched by a route parameter, you can append a regular expression in parentheses (`()`):
>
> ```
> Route path: /user/:userId(\d+)
> Request URL: http://localhost:3000/user/42
> req.params: {"userId": "42"}
> ```

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a regular expression:

```js
router.get(/\/api\/platform\/(?:windows|android)/, async (req, res) => {
  // something
}
```

See [Path examples](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#path-examples); Type: "Regular Expression"

---

Here is a regex example in native JS to test out the route expression:

```js
const route =/\/api\/platform\/(?:windows|android)/;

const requests = [
  '/api/platform/windows',
  '/api/platform/android',
  '/api/platform/macos',
  '/api/platform/linux'
];

console.log(requests.filter(request => route.exec(request)));
```